# Com Error on server

Tags: iis, com

Yesterday i started getting server too busy errors on some websites we are hosting. So I logged on the server and took a look at the event viewer

about 4 time / minutes im getting this error :

Log Name : Application 
Source : Complus 
Event ID : 4689 
error Msg : The run-time environment has detected an inconsistency in its internal state. This indicates a potential instability in the process that could be caused by the custom components running in the COM+ application, the components they make use of, or other factors. Error in d:\longhorn\com\complus\src\comsvcs\threads\stathread.cpp(300), hr = 80070008: CSTAThread: CoGetApartmentID failed

i am wondering if anyone ever got that kind of issue and if yes what is it related to / how can i fix it ?

thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What kind of server is it ? Data server ? Web server ?